# Too long loading page - analytics system

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I would like to ask you for advice related to my own analytics system.
So far my system collects all the clicks and save them in a SQL database.

### First part of analytics.

**The SQL database `logs` looks like this:**

```
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
| id | time                 | address     | address_to                                  | ip             | resolution   | id_guest |
|----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------|
| 1  | 2013-12-03#14:31:35  | index.php   | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VJBBUqr1wM | 89.XX.XXX.6    | 1366x768     | 6        |
| 2  | 2013-12-03#14:48:21  | file.php    | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EWbonj7f18 | 89.XX.XXX.6    | 1366x768     | 6        |
| 3  | 2013-12-03#16:16:55  | contact.php | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o-XIryB2gg | 178.XX.XXX.140 | 1920x1080    | 11       |
| 4  | 2013-12-03#16:21:32  | index.php   | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0M96LyTyX4 | 178.XX.XXX.140 | 1920x1080    | 11       |
| 5  | 2013-12-03#16:44:32  | movies.php  | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUhPA5qIxDQ | 178.XX.XXX.140 | 1920x1080    | 11       |
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

Each click is added to the database as a new record.

All movie on my website is on second table in SQL database (**movies**):

```
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | name                 | address     | tags                |
|----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------|
| 1  | 2013-12-03#14:31:35  | 6VJBBUqr1wM | bass,electro,trance |
| 2  | 2013-12-03#14:48:21  | 0EWbonj7f18 | electro,house,new   |
| 3  | 2013-12-03#16:16:55  | _o-XIryB2gg | electro,party,set   |
| 4  | 2013-12-03#16:21:32  | z0M96LyTyX4 | trance,house,new    |
| 5  | 2013-12-03#16:44:32  | cUhPA5qIxDQ | techno,new,set      |
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Everything works flawlessly. In the database I have all the movies viewed by the user, which I want precisely define, so write down the IP + resolution.

**First question:**
Is this a good method for determining user?

--

### Second part of analytics.

Now I want to use the collected logs and display interface with movies based on browsed materials.
I choose all logs from the database for the user who enters the website.
From the logs I choose identifier film and scan it in the table `components` for take logs and put into an array. For example, a user with `ID = 6` will have an array:

```
array(
    [0] = > bass,
    [1] = > electro,
    [2] = > trance,
    [3] = > electro,
    [4] = > house,
    [5] = > new
);
```

Now I will sort the contents of the array in order of most frequently occurring:

```
array(
    [2] = > electro,
    [1] = > bass,
    [1] = > trance,
    [1] = > house,
    [1] = > new
);
```

On the basis of the contents of the array can show user videos that might interest him.

Everything worked perfectly, but the problem I discovered only now ...
In the table `logs` I've had more than 4.5 million records. As you can imagine, searching of such a large number of records takes a lot of time and enter the site sometimes lasts up to 10 seconds...

I hope my poor English is fairly clear.

Please, any advice how to solve this problem with loading page.

Comment: Are you using indexes? What exactly are you searching for? Does it have to be 100% acurate newest data? You could make some job to analyze the data and prepare the results in some search table every hour or so.

Comment: There is a lot you can consider doing: High performance server, high performance db engine, queries optimization, db optimization, caching etc

Comment: @Uriel_SVK i've never hurt about indexes... Thanks, its helpfull and sounds like my solution to the problem :) From `components` I choose all logs WHERE id = USER_ID. Do you think about CRON ?

Comment: @PatrykSzram yep, you can use cron. Also what are you using the data from logs for? For example if you need users prefered resolution you can just make a search table for prefered resolutions for all users and you can fill it through that cron job

Comment: Please edit your question and show the queries that you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use indexes where needed, hard to tell exactly where - you didnt show any queries - basically you want to have indexed columns in WHERE part of the queries and also in JOINS. You dont have to index column that stays the same most of the time - isloggedin, isadmin, language   or so
2. Make search tables for data you nead to search - for example if you need to know prefered resolution or how many times user had visited a site, you can make a cron job to parse this data for all users and store it in search table. This can be also used to make some statistics if you need it. For those Tags you could have a table with `user_id`, `tag`, `count`
3. If you need only last visited site, last resolution,... just make a table for that, where you can store and update one row for every user

Comment: My vote: Go for 2 (not 1). Indexes in the actual log-files are normally not a good idea since you've got intensive writing in those tables.

Comment: @user247245 that should have no effect on site delay if hes gonna use `INSERT DELAYED` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html If the table is queried it should be indexed